# How can I connect Azure event hubs with outside server via websocket connection to receive and send real time data?

Tags: azure, websocket

I am sorry if the question may seem naive to some. I am still a beginner and a self-learner!

Answer (score 0):

You can add Azure Stream Analytics to query in real time the data you're receiving in your Event Hubs, then use an Azure Function as the output to send the emails.

EDIT: to support Web Sockets, you'll need to add SignalR Service to this stack:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-functions

Comment: I will try it !